# Why is my overloaded >> operator throwing bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I have defined a custom istream operator >> to read from a text file to a container (library) of objects (package)

```
istream& operator>>(istream& ist, library& lib) //js read packages into library
{
    char c;
    while (ist.get(c)){ //js read in package
        string name;
        while(c != ',' || c!= ';'){ //js read file name
            name += c;  
            ist.get(c);
        }

        vector<string> tagz;
        while(c != ';'){    //js read in tags
            ist.get(c);
            string temptag;
            while(c != ','){    
                temptag += c;
                ist.get(c);
                if(c==',') tagz.push_back(temptag); //js add tag to tagz vector
            }
        package temp(name, tagz); //js define new package
        lib.add(temp);  //js add new package to list
        }
    }
    return ist;
}
```

However, when I use the operator in my main function, I get the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I know this is a memory allocation issue, but I can't figure out where the bug is. Any help or input is appreciated!

Comment: `c != ',' || c!= ';'` will always be true; you probably meant `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: Fire up the debugger and figure out what's going on in that while loop.  You should probably have some error checking for those stream operations failing as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here might be loops of this form:

```
 while(c != ';'){    //js read in tags
    ist.get(c);
    ...
 }
```

In the event that `ist` encounters an error (for example, reading past the end of the file or if the connection breaks) before a `;` is read, then this will go into an infinite loop because `ist.get(c)` will leave `c` unchanged. Since your code keeps appending characters to a string, this infinite loop will try to create an unboundedly long string, which will fail when the system runs out of memory for characters.

To fix this, you should probably add some error-checking to this code so that if the stream encounters an error during extraction, your function will exit rather than looping indefinitely.

**EDIT:** As @uk4321 pointed out, there's also an infinite loop here:

```
while(c != ',' || c!= ';') {
     ...
}
```

This statement is always true. Each character has only one value, so every character will compare different to at least one of `,` and `;`. To fix this, try rewriting it as

```
while(c != ',' && c!= ';') {
     ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code right here:

```
        string temptag;
        while(c != ','){    
            temptag += c;
            ist.get(c);
            if(c==',') tagz.push_back(temptag); //js add tag to tagz vector
        }
```

It will create a `string`, assign it to `temptag`, and *then* loop. The `temptag` variable never gets reassigned, so it will be adding the same one to `tagz` every time. This means that when `tagz` gets destructed, it will try to destruct `temptag` multiple times and throw an exception.